# constructing a large multi dimesional vector array

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, multidimensional-array

Right now I have a vector `std::vector<char> myVector(4)` containing any combination of a set of char lets say {@,#,O,*,%,$,!} may be more or less but not many more than that, might not always be 4 members either, but will be constant for any instance one instance.

now I stuck trying to create a data structure that can use an indefinite number of those combination as an index, to another vector.

in pseudo-code I am trying to accomplish:

```
SomeDataStructure['*']['#']['@']['O'] = someData
```

(someData is going to be a small class, but that shouldn't matter)

This is an operation critical piece that needs to run quickly, and will be run very often.

some approached i've tried to reason with were:
a 4 dimensional array, but I can access those without numeric indices. Maybe some form of enumeration could solve this. Edit: would maps be a way to do this?

---

edit:

I resolved this using a map:

```
std::map<std::vector<char>, someData> myMap;
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html

Comment: It is going to be used to look up a sequence up moves(someData) based on what an "organism" see's in its view(myVector). It is the backbone to a real time learning simulator. Therefore, it will be run a lot.

Comment: How big is your set of characters?

Comment: Will there be some sequences of characters that are looked up much more frequently than others? Also, how many combinations of these characters will be used to index into your map?

Comment: There should definitely be some that will be accessed a lot more than other.(as well some that are impossible or unlikely) right now the field of vision covers 4 spaces, I don't plan to make it much more than that. 6 or 10 at the upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of possible characters is limited to 8, you can use an enumeration instead. You'd therefore only need 3-bits to represent each "character". You can pack several of these 3-bit "characters" into a short integer using *bitfields*. The resulting packed integer becomes the index into your `vector<SomeData>`.

The space occupied by this vector would be `space_of_SomeData * 2^(3*number_of_spaces)`. If, for example, `number_of_spaces` is 4, this results in `4096*space_of_SomeData`. This might result in some wasted memory space, but lookups and insertions should be very fast.

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <vector>

enum CharSet
{
    ampersand,
    pound,
    letterOh,
    percent,
    dollar,
    exclamation
};

struct CompositeIndex
{
    union
    {
        struct // Bitfield
        {
            unsigned c0 : 3; // 3 bits
            unsigned c1 : 3; // 3 bits
            unsigned c2 : 3; // 3 bits
            unsigned c3 : 3; // 3 bits
        } chars;

        unsigned int index;
    };
};

unsigned int lookup(CharSet c0, CharSet c1, CharSet c2, CharSet c3)
{
    CompositeIndex ci;
    ci.chars.c0 = c0;
    ci.chars.c1 = c1;
    ci.chars.c2 = c2;
    ci.chars.c3 = c3;
    return ci.index;
}

typedef int SomeClass;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<SomeClass> vec(100);
    vec[lookup(ampersand, percent, dollar, pound)] = 42;
}
```

If you must absolutely work with `char` characters, you can easily create a 256-element lookup table that quickly converts 'char' characters into `CharSet` values.

---

As already discussed by others, you can use a `std::map<std::string, SomeData>` or even (the possibly faster) `std::map<char[4], SomeData, Comparitor>`. If the approximate frequency distribution of different character sequences is known, try inserting the most frequent patterns first in the map. Depending on the internal implementation of the map, this may speed up lookups for the most frequent patterns (they are near the top of the underlying binary search tree).

Comment: As they say Today memory is cheap, but time is still priceless.  In other news, that code example is a work of art, as its direct look up it should be much faster than using map. Plus i get to learn a bunch of new thing.  I would have problems scaling the field of vision much larger than 4, and in the future use the std::map. Also I can't know the frequency because it's based off of the simulation, plus someData is randomly generated. I am trying to get the size of my someData class here, but its not working right. (i am enlarging a vector in it but the size is staying at 24)

Comment: Computing a hashing index may turn out to be just as fast as the bit shifting/masking operations in my bitfield solution. I don't know what hashing functions are used in industrial strength hash maps (such as Boost's `unordered_map`), so I couldn't tell you if it's even worth trying my solution.

Comment: Either way it's going to be a good learning tool. I've had some structs of bool values that I have been want to learn how to compress together. (they are put into vector that is part of someData)

Comment: `sizeof(SomeData)` will not reveal the allocated size of of dynamically allocated members. `sizeof(SomeData)` is computed at compile-time. That's why `sizeof(SomeData)` stays fixed even though you (dynamically) resize it's vector member. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector. When I said `sizeof(SomeData)` in my answer, I assumed it was a POD (plain old data) type.

Comment: Just be aware that different compilers can pack bitfields in different ways. The rules are (unfortunately) quite loose. It's when you serialize bitfields to a file or on a wire that you need to be especially careful.

Answer (score 0):

Does the order of the characters itself have any bearing on what someData might be?  If not (and I suspect that to be the case), then it sounds like what you really want is a hashtable matching strings to a small class.  Hash functions are quick (O(1)) operations, so performance ought not to be a problem.

Take a look at [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) class - it should meet your needs.

Comment: actually the order is going matter, they actually represent distinct positions in relation to a field of vision.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a `char` *is* a number (typically an 8-bit number). As such, you *can* theoretically do a 4-D array with those as the indices. The obvious problem with doing that will be that with a total of 4 bytes for indexing, your array ends up with 2<sup>32</sup> entries. If, for example, that `someData` occupies 32 bits, the array would occupy around 16 gigabytes (of which, apparently, only a minuscule percentage would really be used).

The obvious alternative would be to concatenate the individual characters together into a string, and use that as the key for a map:

```
std::map<std::string, SomeData_t> mymap;

mymap["*#@O"] = someData;
```

Depending on how often you insert versus look up items, you could consider using an `unordered_map` instead. This typically gives slightly faster lookup in exchange for slightly slower insertion.

Comment: I had actually thought about that, never calculated it out, but i knew it had to be huge.

Comment: In the beginning it will be 100% inserts, after some time the number should dwindle(I hope, or else convergence will take forever)

Comment: Also, regarding stringing the characters, wouldn't the small character set produce poor results from a standard has function? (based on my last half an hour of hash table education..)

Comment: @Zak: given the high insertion rate and small character set, I'd probably use `std::map`. It's easy enough to switch to an unordered_map if it ever seems like a good idea.