# Exit with value 1 C++(Vectors)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm a Java programmer trying to get used to C++ and so far NetBeans is not helping me, I'm having Run Failed(exit value 1, total time: 10ms); I've checked some solutions for problems like mine, but It's not working, so far I'm able to understand that usually this error appears with arrays with non-allocated memory, that is not my case(I Guess).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Rover {
private:
    string name;
    int position[2];
    string direction;
    int speed;
public:
    Rover();
    Rover(string name, int x, int y, string direction, int speed);
    void getRoverData();
    void setName(string name);
    string getName();
    void setPosition(int x, int y);
    int getPosition();
    void setDirection(string diretction);
    string getDirection();
    void setSpeed(int speed);
    int getSpeed();
};

Rover::Rover() {
    this->position[0] = 0;
    this->position[1] = 0;
    this->direction = "North";
}

Rover::Rover(string name, int x, int y, string direction, int speed) {
    this->name = name;
    this->position[0] = x;
    this->position[1] = y;
    this->direction = direction;
    this->speed = speed;
}

void Rover::setDirection(string direction) {
    this->direction = direction;
}

void Rover::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Rover::setPosition(int x, int y) {
    this->position[0] = x;
    this->position[1] = y;
}

void Rover::setSpeed(int speed) {
    this->speed = speed;
}

string Rover::getDirection() {
    return this->direction;
}

string Rover::getName() {
    return this->name;
}

int Rover::getPosition() {
   //ToDo -> send array, not value at index, how I can do it?=]
    return this->position[0];
}

int Rover::getSpeed() {
    return this->speed;
}

void Rover::getRoverData() {
    cout << "Rover name is " << this->name << endl;
    cout << "The Rover position is(X,Y) " << this->position[0] << "," << this->position[1] << endl;
    cout << "Rover is going to " << this->direction << endl;
    cout << "Rover speed is(M/s) " << this->speed << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    //vector<Rover> *vectorOfRover = new vector<Rover>();
    vector<Rover> vectorOfRover;
    int i = 0;
    while (sizeof (vectorOfRover) <= 5) {
        string tempName;
        int tempX;
        int tempY;
        string tempDirection;
        int tempSpeed;

        cout << "Enter Rover name " << endl;
        cin >> tempName;
        cout << "Enter X position " << endl;
        cin >>tempX;
        cout << "Enter Y position " << endl;
        cin >> tempY;
        cout << "Enter the Rover direction " << endl;
        cin >> tempDirection;
        cout << "Enter the Rover speed " << endl;
        cin >> tempSpeed;
        Rover r1 = Rover(tempName, tempX, tempY, tempDirection, tempSpeed);
        vectorOfRover.push_back(r1);
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        Rover r = vectorOfRover[j];
        r.getRoverData();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
while (sizeof (vectorOfRover) <= 5) {
```

[`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is evaluated at compile time, so it doesn't depend on the actual number of items in the vector. Most likely `sizeof(std::vector)` is greater than 5 so you skip the loop completely. What you meant is probably

```
while (vectorOfRover.size() <= 5) {
```

And then you go out of bounds here:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
```

Change it to

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

Answer (score -1):

I think part of the problem is calling `sizeof` on a `vector`. That just does not make any sense: `sizeof` is a compile time operator that returns the size in memory of a certain object, thus it will never return the number of elements in a collection, e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector).

Comment: _"sizeof can only be applied to built in types or arrays"_  You're wrong here! In fact `sizeof()` can be applied to any type, if the result is what's reasonably wanted within a particular use case, is a different thing.

Comment: Well `sizeof` will not return how many elements are in the vector, but the [size in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector) of that instance. Edited answer.