# How much memory is required to store a matrix using the armadillo linear algebra package?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am getting the same value on using the sizeOf operator for a matrix of size 100*100 and 1*1 respectively.

```
mat A(100,100),B(1,1);
A.randu();
B.randu();
cout<<"Memory requested for A:"<<sizeOf(A);
cout<<"Memory requested for B:"<<sizeOf(B);
```

Output:
Memory requested for A:160
Memory requested for B:160

Well how do I get the actual memory required by the code for each variable A,B.

Comment: What is `sizeOf`? Is it some function in the Armadillo library? The type `mat` only stores pointers to the memory that it allocates. There's probably some member function that returns the number of elements in the matrix being managed by a `mat` instance. Multiply the number returned by that with the size of each matrix element.

Comment: @Raw N : It returns only 160 , whenever I use sizeOf(). For both variable A and B

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof() a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) type stores an array of doubles, so to get the size of the array as bytes:

```
A.n_elem * sizeof(double)
```

The total amount of memory used by `A` is `sizeof(A) + (A.n_elem * sizeof(double))`.