# Armadillo Sparse Matrix Size in Bytes

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I would like to assess how large Armadillo sparse matrices are. The question is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29725068) regarding dense matrices.

Consider the following example:

```
void some_function(unsigned int matrix_size) {
  arma::sp_mat x(matrix_size, matrix_size);

  // Steps entering some non-zero values

  std::cout << sizeof(x) << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, `sizeof` does, as in the dense matrix case, not return the size of the matrix itself, but rather the size of a pointer or some other small object. The size of the sparse matrix should not simply be the number of non-zero elements times the data type's size. Armadillo stores sparse matrices in a compressed format. And on top of the cell values, there should also be a matrix or vectors storing the cell indices. And I guess that the matrix also has a header storing information about the object.

Comment: Unless Armadillo provides some function to do what you want, there is no standard C++ functionality to get the total amount of storage used by the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three key properties:

- n_rows
- n_cols and
- n_nonzero

The last value represents the number of `cells 0 <= n_nonzero <= (n_rows*n_cols)` which have a value.

You can use this to know the density (which is also displayed as a percentage with `.print`, e.g.

```
[matrix size: 3x3; n_nonzero: 4; density: 44.44%]

     (1, 0)         0.2505
     (0, 1)         0.9467
     (0, 2)         0.2513
     (2, 2)         0.5206
```

I used these properties to implement sp_matrix serialization before: [How to serialize sparse matrix in Armadillo and use with mpi implementation of boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267414/how-to-serialize-sparse-matrix-in-armadillo-and-use-with-mpi-implementation-of-b/67275320#67275320)

The actual number of bytes allocated will be roughly correlating to `n_nonzero`, but you have to account for /some/ overhead. In practice the best way to measure **actual** allocations is by using instrumented allocators, or (the logical extension of that idea) memory profilers. See e.g. [How to find the memory occupied by a boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678402/how-to-find-the-memory-occupied-by-a-boostdynamic-bitset/65720556#65720556)