# Declaration of std::vector works with forward declared classes?

Tags: c++

I have a header file like the below -

```
// abc.hpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace A 
{
    namespace B 
    {   
        struct abc 
        {   
            std::string _type;
        };  

        using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
    }   

}
```

I am using forward declaration in another header file.

```
// con.hpp
#include <vector>

namespace A 
{
    namespace B 
    {   
        struct abc; // Forward Declaration
        using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
    }   

    namespace C
    {   
        class N
        {   
            public:
                B::abc_vector foo(std::string type);
        };  
    }   
}
```

What really confuses me is that my code compiles and works.

How is the vector allowed to be declared with incomplete type?
I think that it shouldn't be able to decide the **size of abc**.

```
using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
```

The below is the code I used to test my header files.
Strange enough, that it compiles and works all fine.

```
#include "con.hpp"
#include "abc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    namespace C
    {   
        B::abc_vector N::foo(std::string type)
        {   
            B::abc a;
            a._type = type;

            B::abc_vector d;
            d.push_back(a);
            return d;
        }   
    }   
}

int main()
{
    A::C::N n;
    auto container = n.foo("test");

    for (const auto& i : container)
          std::cout << i._type << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I think that it shouldn't be able to decide the size of abc."_ What makes you think it needs to?

Comment: I think that works, because the type is the defined by the time you use it in a function.

Comment: I read it in an answer here - 
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346/why-cant-a-forward-declaration-be-used-for-a-stdvector)

**The compiler needs to know how big "B" is before it can generate the appropriate layout information.**

Comment: @badola Hint: the size of an `std::vector<T>` is independent from the size of `T` and the number of elements in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting topic (at least to me) and applies to other std containers.

Originally the standard made it undefined behaviour to instantiate a container of an incomplete type. However implementations did not disallow it. This was in all likelihood not deliberate, but merely a side-effect of the fact that elements in (for example the vector) are stored in a memory location that is referenced by a pointer.

Thus the size of an element does not need to be known until an element is actually required - during the instantiation of a member function of the vector.

Here is a starting point for research if you'd like to explore further:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4056.html

Comment: Thanks @Richard Hodges, this was a much more convincing answer. :)

Can you point to more articles, where I can read about it..?

Comment: Hmm well your question prompted me to remember something I read in the boost documentation some time ago. This link contains a fairly complete narrative http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types

Answer (score 3):

The code line

```
using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
```

only **introduces a type alias** for `std::vector<abc>`. That doesn't require, by any means, the size of `abc` since no object of type `abc` is allocated at all. Only a new type is declared.

```
B::abc_vector d;
```

Indeed needs the definition of `abc`. Nevertheless it works because at this point `abc` already has been defined because the header file `abc.hpp` has been included.

---

You are referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346/why-cant-a-forward-declaration-be-used-for-a-stdvector), where

```
std::vector<B> v;
```

is "done." This is not the same as what you did. You just introduced a type alias. `std::vector<B> v;` actually **defines** a variable. Therefore the definition of `B` is mandatory.

---

Note that

```
using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef std::vector<abc> abc_vector;
```

Maybe this makes it a bit clearer why the size of `abc` isn't necessary to know at this time point in compilation.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you think `B::abc_vector d;` does.

Comment: Hm probably because the second example does include `abc.hpp`. Add on this pointing out that the question is flawed, and you've got it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, "already has been defined" refers to the fact that "abc.hpp" has been included and `abc` is defined there. And `B::abc_vector d;` does `std::vector<int> d;`, right?

Comment: No, it does `std::vector<abc> d;`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, crap.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting observation. Both `GCC5.2` and `CLANG3.6` compile following code.

```
struct A;

std::vector<A> my_func(); //Definition of my_func is in some CPP file
```

But throw errors for

```
struct A;

std::vector<A> v;
```

And reasoning for this is size of vector won't change for different type it is holding. See following code snippet.

```
struct B{int i; int j;};
struct C{int a,b,c;};

std::vector<B> pp;
std::vector<C> qq;

int main()
{
  std::cout<<sizeof(pp)<<'\n';
  std::cout<<sizeof(qq)<<'\n';
}
```

Output

```
24

24
```

But for `std::vector<A> v` it has to provide the `Allocator<A>()` as well.  And allocator required members of `struct A` like constructor, copy constructor, destructor etc. 
Also one important thing to note here is `pointer arithmetic for incomplete type is not allowed.`

If you see the errors thrown by CLANG, it clearly says same.

```
In file included from /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler115920-68-1xsb8x7/example.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/vector:64:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'A'
- this->_M_impl._M_start); }
^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:253:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Vector_base<A, std::allocator<A> >::~_Vector_base' requested here
vector()
^
```

Everything else is quite straight forward.

Following is a typedef , so compiler does need to know about size.

```
using abc_vector = std::vector<abc>;
```

So, the code structure discussed in question is good to go ahead with.

Comment: I am curious, will you please explain why does the size of -
std::vector<B> pp;
std::vector<C> qq;
Both return 24.

Comment: Nevermind, I got the explanation here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector