# How the following C++11 code should work?

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang

The following code outputs different results on various compilers:

- 2,1,2 on Visual Studio 2013
- 2,2,2 on Visual Studio 2015
- 2,1,1 on GCC5/c++14
- 2,2,2 on Clang 3.7 with Microsoft Codegen
- 2,1,2 on Clang 3.6/c++11 under Ubuntu 14.04

Finally, how it should work according to C++ standard?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Value;
using Array = std::vector<Value>;

class Value
{
public:
    Value(const Array &)
    {
    }

    Value(int)
    {
    }
};

void foo(Array const& a)
{
    printf("%d\n", (int)a.size());
}

int main()
{
    Array a1 = { 1, 2 };
    foo(a1);
    foo(Array{ a1 });
    foo(Array({ a1 }));
}
```

P.S. The same issue reveals with json_spirit library from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed in C++11, as you have created a `std::vector` type with an incomplete type as an argument.  The value type of a `vector` *must* be complete when you create the `std::vector<T>` type.

As an ill-formed program (and I'm not aware of a requirement for a diagnostic), any and all behavior is legal under the standard.

The requirement that `vector`'s `T` be a complete type is probably over-specified (there is really no convincing reason to have that requirement), but it exists.  Asking the same question in C++1z will lead to a different answer, as that requirement was relaxed.

---

Ignoring that issue, philosophically:

```
Array a1 = { 1, 2 };
```

this should generate a `std::vector` with two elements.

```
foo(a1);
```

This should pass `a1` to `foo`, as the types match exactly.

```
foo(Array{ a1 });
```

Here we have `{}`.  My rule of thumb with `{}` is "if it is non-empty, and it *can* match an `initializer_list` constructor, it *must*".

As `a1` can be converted to a `Value`, `Array{ a1 }` is an array of one `Value`.

```
foo(Array({ a1 }));
```

Here we look at an argument of the constructor `Array` that can be called with `{ a1 }`.  Both the `std::initalizer_list<Value>` and the `Array&&` constructors can be.

Which is called should not matter: The `Array&&` constructor in turn sends the `{a1}` to the `std::initalizer_list<Value>` constructor.

So my opinion is that it should print `211`.  This is, however, merely an opinion on what the could *ought* to do, not an analysis of what the standard says it should do, as the C++11 standard quite clearly states your program is ill-formed.

On the other hand, hiding the copy constructor seems rude.

On the final hand, you did write a simply insane type.  Insane behavior is to be expected.

A more practical concern might be when the `Value` type has a `template` constructor that happens to also match a `std::vector<Value>`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, compilers' determination to match braced initializers with constructors taking `std::initializer_list`s is so strong, it prevails even if the best-match `std::initializer_list` constructor can't be called (Scott Meyers).

```
Array a1 = { 1, 2 }; // Call Initiliazer list constructor foo(a1); // print 2

foo(Array{ a1 }); // Call Initiliazer list constructor.  Print 1

foo(Array({ a1 })); // Call Initiliazer list constructor.  Print 1
```

According to the standard, the result must be: 2,1,1

Yakk's answer mention that the program is ill-formed in C++11. But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213507/declaration-of-stdvector-works-with-forward-declared-classes) is very interesting.