# Can a class member offset change if a vector member changes size?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, integer-arithmetic

If I have a class like:

```
class foo 
{
    std::vector<int> bar;
    int a;
};
```

will the offset of `int a` stay constant throughout runtime? My understanding is that `std::vector<int> bar` can be resized and that vectors have the items they contain in contiguous memory. If this is the case, then if `bar` gets resized during runtime, wouldn't that change the offset of `a`?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector

Comment: @fas That link is not related to the OP's question actually, They're asking if changing a vector member's size affects the layout.

Comment: The size of a `vector` *object* doesn't change *regardless* of how many (if any) items are in the vector. The dynamic sequence the vector maintains internally can certainly change memory footprint, but the vector object itself, as an object, is going to be size-constant, and as such so shall (a) any instance of `foo`, and (b) the offset of the member `a`.

Comment: @cigien it's kinda the same thing OP asks for: difference between `sizeof` (size of object itself which is constant and indent depends on it) and `vector::size`

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes :) I was just clarifying that the OP was asking, since the suggested link doesn't cover that.

Comment: @fas Ok, that link does mention sizeof. I don't think it's going to be helpful to the OP though, since there's no mention of structs or members.

Comment: @WhozCraig No worries, I was just confused for a moment :p

Comment: @WhozCraig cigien fas thanks everyone!

Comment: Conjecture: In C++ no object changes its size at run time. Is that so?

Comment: No.   `sizeof()` any object in C++ is fixed at compile time.   `std::vector<AnyType>::size()` and `sizeof(std::vector<AnyType>`) are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ no object changes its size at run time — all complete types are of known and constant size. This is reflected by the fact that the result of the `sizeof` operator is a constexpr; it is determined at compile time.

It is well possible and indeed not uncommon that an object contains a pointer which may over the course of the run time point to memory of varying sizes; but that memory resides elsewhere and is unrelated to the object (except for the coincidental fact that a pointer in the object points to it). In particular, it is not nominally part of the object and does not influence its size. `std::vector` is such a type containing a pointer. Where that pointer points to, and how much memory is available at that location, does not affect the size of the vector object as such.